# Data binding & MVVM. Show DatePickerDIalog by clicking on the button

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

Now I have this code:

```
class MyFragment : DaggerFragment() {
    ...
    private fun setTimePickerDialog() {
        binding.timeButton.setOnClickListener{
            val calendar = viewModel.calendar
            val curHourOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
            val curMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
            val dialog = TimePickerDialog(context, { _, hourOfDay, minute ->
                 val c = Calendar.getInstance()
                 c.set(1970, 0, 1, hourOfDay, minute)
                 viewModel.time.value = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(c.time)
            }, curHourOfDay, curMinute, true)
            dialog.show()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to take advantage of the DataBinding library and not write `setOnClickListener` in my fragment. But I can't move this code to the `ViewModel`, because a context is required. What is a clean way to show DatePickerDialog by clicking on the button using DataBinding and MVVM?

Comment: Do you have your `ViewModel` instance inside your `XML` layout file?

Comment: @MostafaAryannejad, yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why can't you  use a handler inside the xml instead of the viewmodel. Then get the click using the handler.
In your XML -->use a variable called handler whose type is the path of your fragment

```
<data class ="binding">
    <variable name="handler" type="com.MyFragment"/>
</data>

android:onClick="@{()->handler.onDisplayTimePickerDialogClick()}
```

Comment: Sir @Abraham Mathew is it right to implement in the fragment? any idea about using Bindingadapter to fire up the datepicker and select the date?

Comment: I have not yet tried that, but if you want to get that click listener you can try it with binding adapter it's possible.

Comment: this is one of the reasons, why I don't use databinding

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for, can be achieved using `LiveData` from the architecture component, it can also be done with any other observable tools such as rxJava.

The first step is to define an observable in our `ViewModel`, and implementing a function that when the user clicks, it invokes the observable.

**ViewModel:**

```
MutableLiveData<Boolean> timePickerDialogData = new MutableLiveData<>();
...

public void onDisplayTimePickerDialogClick() {
    timePickerDialogData.setValue(true);
}

...
public LiveData<Boolean> getTimePickerDialogData() {
        return timePickerDialogData;
    }
```

The second step is to observe the observable in the fragment and listen to its value changes. when the observable is invoked from `ViewModel` we can display the dialog.

**Fragment:**

```
private void observeTimePickerDialogData() {
    viewModel.getTimePickerDialogData().observe(this, display -> {
    if(display) setTimePickerDialog(); // Display TimePickerDialog
    });
}
```

Finally, the `onClick` logic inside the `XML` layout file using android data binding.

**XML:**

`android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.onDisplayTimePickerDialogClick()}"`

Comment: Hi @MostafaAryannejad, how would you go about observing or retrieving the value selected from the Date/Time picker?  Would you use another observable or implement a callback to get the selected date/time?

Comment: @Byron, Hi, I'm observing the value in the **Fragment** as I have included the code in my answer.
 In my **Fragment** I'm getting the `observable` from the **ViewModel** and starting to observe it.

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be done more directly with a onClickMethod on the ViewModel. By passing the view as param into the onClick-Method we can use the view's context to start the TimePickerDialog:

My clickable TextView looks like this (only relevant attributes contained):

```
    <TextView
        android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewmodel.onChangeTimeClicked(view)}"/>
```

My ViewModel's onClicked-Method then looks like this:

```kotlin
    fun onChangeTimeClicked(v: View) {
        val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _,_,_ ->
            // Some Implementation
        }
        TimePickerDialog(
            v.context,          // <-- Context from view on which was clicked
            timeSetListener,
            0,
            0,
            true
        ).show()
    }
```

I know the question is a bit older but as I had this issue now I found this thread and maybe it is also still useful for somebody.

Comment: Noooo, you cannot have a view dependency inside the ViewModel

Comment: I think it should be save in this case, can you please explain your doubts?

Comment: When you have the view reference inside the ViewModel you are basically breaking the MVVM, as the ViewModel was thought to be Android dependency free in order to make tests easier